# How to change order and grouping of entries in a matplotlib legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is what my legend looks like right now:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

My code:

```
ax = cars.plot.barh(stacked=True)
ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.legend(loc="center", ncols=4)
```

I tried adding the line `plt.plot(0, np.zeros([1, 3]), '.', ms=0, label='fake')` and `ax.plot(0, np.zeros([1, 3]), '.', ms=0, label='fake')` but the result is this:

[image]

The entries labelled "fake" should be added from the back. I can then change the label from "fake" to "" to create empty entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is explicitly supported. You can work around it by adding additional, fake entries to the legend (in your case 3). Consider:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()

# Actual data
for i in range(13):
    plt.plot(np.random.random(), np.random.random(), '.', label=chr(ord('A') + i))

# Fake data, for the legend
plt.plot(0, np.zeros([1, 3]), '.', ms=0, label=' ')

plt.legend(ncol=4)
plt.show()  # or plt.savefig('figname.png')
```

Here I've used a marker size (`ms`) of `0`, ensuring that the plotted fake data points will not appear on either the plot nor the legend.

Comment: But when I add plt.plot(0, np.zeros([1, 3]), '.', ms=0, label=' ') the 3 fake entries are added in front of the legend. How do I add them in the back?

Comment: You should add them last, as in my example.

Comment: The order does not matter. Adding them first or last always results in the fake entries being in the front.

Comment: That's odd. What happens if you copy-paste my example code into a Python prompt?

Comment: You example works. I have no clue why my code does not work.

Comment: @Xtiaan Could you update the question with a complete (yet minimal) example?

Answer (score 0):

You could add some dummy legend handles to fill up the empty space:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

labels = 'abcdefghijklm'
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    plt.bar([i], (i + 1) ** 2, color=plt.cm.turbo_r(i / len(labels)), label=label)
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
dummy_handle = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 0, 0, color='none', label='')
plt.legend(handles=handles + 3*[dummy_handle], ncol=4)
plt.show()
```

[image: legend with 4 filled-up columns]